# Enabling FTS4 on sqlite3 gem

Tags: ruby, sqlite, rubygems, fts3

In order to use FTS on SQLite, I had to compile it with the proper configuration. It worked and when I type "sqlite3" in a shell, I can use full text search.

Unfortunately in my Rails app, using the sqlite3 gem, I get the following error:

> SQLite3::SQLException: no such module: fts4: SELECT "items".* FROM
>   "items"

It seems that the gem isn't pointing to the right SQLite version. Any clue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried rebuilding your `sqlite3` gem? That did the trick for me.

Comment: I guess it's the thing to do. I ended up giving up SQLite and using MongoDB with Solr.